# Crystal Report in Visual Studio from Object

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, reporting, .net

I'm adding crystal reports to my solution, which is divide in different projects, but I cannot select the data source as an object from another project in my solution.

The thing that I want to do is to fill a report with the result of a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your method is returning a dataset or a datatable. Otherwise you will have to keep on adding the information returned from your method to a dataset in the code where you will be calling the report and use the SetDataSource to fill the report with your data.
Please refer the link given below

[Creating Crystal Reports using C# with Datasets](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12694/Creating-Crystal-Reports-using-C-with-Datasets)

Comment: Thank for your answer, but I want to connect to an entity object, well with an object list.
Is that possible or I need to send all that content to a dataset?